# Laravel 8 how to split url into seo friendly?

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 8 and currently my url is looking as

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?country_id_to=1
```

and I want to set URL as

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/uk/en/pakistan
```

In each route. Ihave no idea to do it.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing) page?

Answer (score 1):

To add on @Douwe de Haan comment - and be more precise have a look at this page: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters

For your example you could do

```
Route::get('/{localization}/{language}/{country}', function ($localization, $language, $country) {
    // your code
});
```

Where

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/uk/en/pakistan`

Would now result in

```
$localization = "uk";
$language = "en";
$country = "pakistan";
```

This will obviously also work with a controller.

If you want to reference an entity not by its ID but by a custom field you can do that as well

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name